# Usage of Phrase 'Hit the Bricks'

Tags: phrases, word-usage

Can we use the phrase 'Hit the bricks' at the context of asking people to work hard?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally not.

**Hit the Bricks** can be thought of as a synonym for 'hit the road' or 'get out of here'. The 'bricks' in question originally referred to paving stones in the road. To hit them meant to start walking on them - preferably away from the person who told you to do so.

Comment: alright, I understood. A man shouting during the team meeting used this. It then means perform or leave :) thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 2):

As LessPop points out it is generally a reference to leaving.

It could be construed to mean "go work hard," but it would have to be highly contrived:

I can imagine a boss telling his underling the details of a job. Giving him a bunch of warnings about the quality expected, etc. And, then following it up with "Now, *go hit the bricks!*".

The meaning would still be:  get out of here and start working. But, the get working hard would probably be implied.

Again, it is a highly contrived example to shoehorn the phrase into the meaning you asked for.

Some better idioms:

> Put your nose to the grindstone.
>   Put your back into it.
>   Go work your heart out.

Comment: @MuthukumarPalaniappan My pleasure.  As a bit of advice:  the scenario you gave in comments to LessPop would have been helpful in the question itself. It would have focused the answers a bit.

Answer (score 1):

The only context where "Hit the Bricks" would imply working hard would be if the employees were door-to-door salesmen and going out on the street would be how they did their job.